# How to redirect stdout from right to left

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe

This works perfectly :

```
./foo | ./bar
```

But I'd like something like that :

```
./bar <| ./foo
```

So I can pipe the other way around and change foo's arguments faster in command line.

The pipe needs to be realtime - my `foo` program does never return.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Not really a pipe but you might use `./bar <(./foo)`

Comment: or `./bar < <(./foo)` if `bar` is a script.

Comment: How would that be faster? Are you just looking for the shell shortcuts like Ctrl+A to go to the beginning and Alt+F to move forward one word at a time?

Comment: Yet shell shortcuts may be useful, I still have to press those key multiple times to get the cursor on the desired argument, whereas having the cursor directly at the end makes me win seconds

Comment: It takes you seconds to type Ctrl+A?

Comment: Ctrl+A and Alt+F are faster than moving cursor to left. But it is even more faster to "up-arrow and edit". See Peter Cordes comments below. Thanks for suggestion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
./bar < <( ./foo )
```

For example: `cat < <(echo "hello there!")`

To understand how it works, consider parts of the script separately.

This syntax: `cat < /path/to/file` will read the file `/path/to/file` and pipe it as stdin to `cat`.

This syntax: `<(echo "hello there!")` means to execute the command and attach the stdout to a file descriptor like `/dev/fd/65`. The result of the whole expression is a text like `/dev/fd/65`, and a command run in parallel and feeding that file descriptor.

Now, combined, the script will run the right command, pipe it to a file descriptor, convert that file descriptor to stdin for the left command, and execute the left command.

There is no overhead that I'd know of, it's exactly the same as `a | b`, just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 10):

A simple and proper way can be to define a foobar function,

```
foobar () { ./foo "$@" | ./bar ; }
```

(either in the command line, as needed, or in some startup scripts, such as ".bashrc" for example).
 Then whenever you do :

```
foobar "this"  that   "and this also"
```

it will do

```
./foo  this   that   "and this also" | ./bar
```

Comment: Yup, I do this all the time to make it easy to up-arrow and edit the part of the command I want to change, without having to ctrl-left-arrow all the way to it.  You can even leave the function definition as part of the command:  `foobar() { printf '%s\n' -x "$1" -y "$2" blah blah "${@:3}" | grep -v 123; };     foobar a b abc 'cd ef'`.  So you can easily tweak the function definition if you think of something else.  (`"${@:3}"` expands to the positional parameters starting with 3, skipping the two we already used.)

Comment: You can do useful stuff like `local IFS=` inside a function, and calculate some variables based on the function args.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do something like that with a named pipe:

```
mypipe=$(mktemp -d /tmp/XXXXXX)/pipe
mkfifo $mypipe
grep something < $mypipe & tail > $mypipe -f  some_input_file 
rm $mypipe
```

or put the unchanging part of the command in a shell script:

```
./foo "$@" | ./bar
```

and give the arguments to `foo` on the script command line:

```
./myscript <args to foo>
```