# redirect from right to left into code block

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Consider this scenario:

```
diff file.txt <( cat file.txt | grep -v '^\s*#'| sed '/^$/d' )
```

this is an example of redirect from right to left, in which you process a file and redirect the result as input to `diff`. Similar use case has been proposed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554034/498339), which also works fine.

However, attempt to redirect result of file processing to a code block in a similar fashion fails:

```
  while read I; do
    …
  done <( cat $FIL | <do_something_here> )
```

`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Or, if you try this:

```
done < <( cat $FIL | <do_something_here> )
```

`Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

How do you redirect output of some process to code block as input?

Comment: Correction: There is no redirection in your first command. There is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution). In the answer you link to, there is a redirection with a process substitution. That said, `while ... done < <(...)` works fine enough (here's an old example from this site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9789/70524). Please show the whole code which gives `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: Similar: [Subshell and process substitution](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/364002)

Answer (score 3):

`<(...)` *process substitution* is a feature of the Korn shell. It is also available in zsh and bash. `rc` and derivatives and `fish` also have process substitution support but with a different syntax, while in the yash shell `<(...)` is syntax for a different feature: *process redirection*.

The wording of that *Syntax error: redirection unexpected* error suggests your shell is an Almquist shell derivative such as `dash`. AFAIK, neither *process substitution* nor *process redirection* have been added to any `ash` derivative.

`while ...; done <(cmd)` would work in `yash`, `while ...; done < <(cmd)` would work in AT&T ksh, zsh and bash, but neither are standard `sh` syntax and neither would work in `dash`.

In `dash` (or any `sh` implementation), you'd need `cmd | while ...; done`, though note that in `dash`, that while loop would run in a subshell.

You could do:

```
while ...; done << EOF
$(cmd)
EOF
```

Though beware it stores the whole output of `cmd` (stripped of all NUL characters (in `dash` at least) and all trailing newline characters) in memory (and adds back one extra newline character).

In any case, [using a `while read` loop is often an indication you're taking the wrong approach](/q/169716), especially if it's just for text processing.